# CoreNLP constituency parsing

Tags: stanford-nlp

How would you describe the status of constituency parsing in CoreNLP? Is it maintained-yet-not-being-improved as the package has moved on ([as of 3.5.3?](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/history.html)) to dependency parsing, thusly aligning with the recent decade's computational linguistics key fashion of research?

I wonder whether the [java-nlp-user mailing list](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/contact.html) is not the more appropriate place for this discussion, but a short authoritative answer would be much appreciated, if there is one.

Since dependency parsing probably reaches very good accuracy using neural state-of-the-art, would you recommend any package for converting from dependency to constituency parses?

Is there any form of (noisy) conversion code provided in CoreNLP, for converting from its dependency parses to constituency parses? Only a rule-based conversion in the *opposite* direction [appears to be provided for some languages](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/parse.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are not actively developing constituency parsing in the Java Stanford CoreNLP package any more.  I think any future improved constituency parsers will be in Python and neural based.  I believe AllenNLP has such an implementation, and it's possible in the future we will add a neural model to our [Python StanfordNLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/index.html) package.

We do not offer any type of dependency to constituency conversion to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks. I am marking this as the correct answer given that an authoritative answer was requested as it seems to come from the Stanford NLP group maintaining StanfordCore. I guess good to know about [StanfordNLP, the python project](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/) while at it.

Comment: I guess it remains to be seen how much effort and support effort goes into the latter compared to the former Java implementation, going forward. In case you have some kind of support policy for the new StanfordNLP python product, please kindly let me know the correct communication channel to inquire about it, it surely goes outside the scope of my original post here.